# I'm getting a "Debug Assertion Failed!" error during runtime of my app. The failure happens in the mfc140d.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, assert

I suddenly started receiving this failure and I cannot figure out why. In the error message, the program is listed as mfc140d.dll and the specific file as "...\mfc\winctrl1.cpp". It seems only windows references this section of code. Specifically, it is failing at "void CComboBox::MeasureItem(…)" function.

Before, I was running my application just fine. I can't imagine what would have happened to cause this error to suddenly show up. Truth be told, I'm pretty unsure of what this code does as is. I know very little about mfc apps.

```cpp
void CComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); }
void CComboBox::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); }
int CComboBox::CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); return 0; }
void CComboBox::DeleteItem(LPDELETEITEMSTRUCT)
    { /* default to nothing */ }

BOOL CComboBox::OnChildNotify(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    LRESULT* pResult)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        ASSERT(pResult == NULL);       // no return value expected
        DrawItem((LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam);
        break;
…
```

Comment: And where in *your* code does it happen? What are you doing in *your* code? When in the debugger, go up the call-stack to your code.

Comment: In Visual Studio there is a `Stack Frame` combo box on the debug toolbar. When this breaks into the debugger switch the stack frame to your code to see the line of your program that caused this.

Comment: Using your debugger, look one stack frame up to see what called `MeasureItem`.  Here's a nice blog post from Eric Lippert: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: [Override this member function to implement drawing for an owner-draw CComboBox object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#drawitem). Looks like you created an owner-draw combo box but didn't specify how to draw anything. The `CComboBox` doesn't know how to draw your custom items.

Comment: Is there a reason this would happen running the debug version, but not release?

Comment: Indeed there is. The `ASSERT` macro compiles to nothing, when the `NDEBUG` preprocessor symbol is defined. The `NDEBUG` preprocessor symbol is defined by default in release build configurations. This is documented, too: [*"In the Release version of MFC, ASSERT does not evaluate the expression and thus will not interrupt the program."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ew16s3zc(v=vs.140))

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the call stack seems flooded with entirely Microsoft functions. The nearest function call that may be something my team wrote, I am told by visual studio cannot be found. I will keep looking though.

Comment: The call stack isn't going to show you, why this failed. This fails, because something is *missing* in the call stack, namely your overrides for the MFC-provided placeholders. Raymond Chen already linked you to the information you need to solve this.

Comment: Could the control properties in the resource (.RC) file been tweaked and changed the properties of your combobox to be *owner drawn*?  This is not C++ code, but the control's properties in the RC file definitely affects the behavior of your code.